# The Godot Engine Editor's IDE/GUI seems to be slow and to ignore mouse interaction

Tags: godot

I'm using `Godot_v3.2.1-stable_win64.exe`(current Godot version) on my **Windows 10**. When running a project everything seems to work fine but when using the actual IDE of the Godot engine it seems like the IDE screen doesn't *update* fluidly on every mouse interaction but like only every 5 seconds instead (as like FPS would be low).

So mostly on hovering or clicking something it would light up or be triggered after you clicked on some *other* thing *elsewhere* (which is stupid of course).

This makes it even impossible to hit a button sometimes in the IDE.
E.g. when renaming a file a Window/Box for renaming pops up but you do not see it, because the IDE screen isn't updated. So if you don't blindly click on the box (which you don't see) the option for renaming is lost, because the box closes when clicking anywhere else. See what I mean?

Thank you for listening. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/23069). Try updating your graphics driver to the latest version *provided by Intel* (not your OEM).

Comment: hey, thx! the link points to a lot of information and in deed I use an Intel Core i5 as 'Intel HD Graphics'. I should try updating it. At the moment I just checked "Editor/Editor Settings.../(General)/Interface/Editor/Update Continuously" to _get around_ the problem.